# Looping basic Javascript game with a win condition

Tags: javascript

How can I loop my game of rock, paper, scissors and have it keep score with a win condition?

I have tried to create a "game" function that loops the rounds of RPS until the player or computer reaches a score of 5. However, I can't get the scores to stick, nor does the game loop.

```js
playerSelection = prompt( ' Enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors');
let winner = 0;
let humanScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

function computerPlay() {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 + 1));
    if(number == 1)
        return 'Rock';
    else if(number == 2)
        return 'Paper';
    else return 'Scissors';
}

let computerSelection = computerPlay();
playerSelection = playerSelection.toUpperCase();
computerSelection = computerSelection.toUpperCase();



function game() {
    while( humanScore <= 5 || computerScore <= 5) {
        playRound();

    }
}


function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if( playerSelection === 'ROCK' && computerSelection === 'SCISSORS') {
        humanScore +=1;
        return playerSelection + ' wins vs ' + computerSelection + '. Congratulations!';
    } else if( playerSelection === 'ROCK' && computerSelection === 'PAPER') {
        computerScore +=2;
        return playerSelection + ' loses vs ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
    } else if( playerSelection === 'ROCK' && computerSelection === 'ROCK') {
        return playerSelection + ' ties with ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
    } else if( playerSelection === 'PAPER' && computerSelection === 'ROCK') {
        humanScore +=1;
        return playerSelection + ' wins vs ' + computerSelection + '. Congratulations!';
    } else if( playerSelection === 'PAPER' && computerSelection === 'PAPER') {
        return playerSelection + ' ties with ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
    } else if( playerSelection === 'PAPER' && computerSelection === 'SCISSORS') {
        computerScore +=2;
        return playerSelection + ' loses vs ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
    } else if( playerSelection === 'SCISSORS' && computerSelection === 'SCISSORS') {
        return playerSelection + ' ties with ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
    } else if( playerSelection === 'SCISSORS' && computerSelection === 'PAPER') {
        humanScore += 1;
        return playerSelection + ' wins vs ' +computerSelection + '. Congratulations!';
    } else if( playerSelection === 'SCISSORS' && computerSelection === 'ROCK') {
        computerScore +=2;
        return playerSelection + ' loses vs ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
    } else return 'Enter a valid move! Refresh the damn page!';

    win_condition();
}

function win_condition() {
    if( humanScore === 5 ) {
        return 'Player Wins!';
    }
    if( computerScore === 5 ) {
        return 'Computer wins!';
    }
}
```

The program executes through one time and works, but doesn't repeat like I expect it to.

Comment: Create a function that takes user's input and generates computer's choice and performs comparison. Now create a variable that keeps a score and for every cycle, call the previously created function

Comment: You may want to call the functions you defined, somewhere. `game()` is never called, for example. Also, you ask for use input *outside* of a loop.

Comment: I dont see the `game` function getting called anywhere. Also `playRound` function expects two parameters but is called with none.

Comment: Also `win_condition();` will never be called, your final condition statement will always be called last `else return 'Enter a valid move! Refresh the damn page!'`

Comment: @Rajesh `win_condition` is at the end of the function block. That code will never be reached because of the returned else statement. - That's just one small thing out of a million.

Answer (score 0):

I tried fixing your code as below and it works fine now.

- Game method is called initially.
- Game rounds are controlled / iterated through game method.
- Condition for next round is altered to `while( humanScore <= 5 && computerScore <= 5) {`
- Alerts are added to show messages after each round and final winner.

```js
let winner = 0;
let humanScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

function computerPlay() {
  let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 + 1));
  if (number == 1)
    return 'Rock';
  else if (number == 2)
    return 'Paper';
  else return 'Scissors';
}

game();

function game() {
  while (humanScore <= 5 && computerScore <= 5) {
    let playerSelection = prompt(' Enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors');
    let computerSelection = computerPlay();
    playerSelection = playerSelection.toUpperCase();
    computerSelection = computerSelection.toUpperCase();
    alert(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
  }
  alert(win_condition());
}


function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection == 'ROCK' && computerSelection == 'SCISSORS') {
    humanScore += 1;
    return playerSelection + ' wins vs ' + computerSelection + '. Congratulations!';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'ROCK' && computerSelection == 'PAPER') {
    computerScore += 2;
    return playerSelection + ' loses vs ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'ROCK' && computerSelection == 'ROCK') {
    return playerSelection + ' ties with ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'PAPER' && computerSelection == 'ROCK') {
    humanScore += 1;
    return playerSelection + ' wins vs ' + computerSelection + '. Congratulations!';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'PAPER' && computerSelection == 'PAPER') {
    return playerSelection + ' ties with ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'PAPER' && computerSelection == 'SCISSORS') {
    computerScore += 2;
    return playerSelection + ' loses vs ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'SCISSORS' && computerSelection == 'SCISSORS') {
    return playerSelection + ' ties with ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'SCISSORS' && computerSelection == 'PAPER') {
    humanScore += 1;
    return playerSelection + ' wins vs ' + computerSelection + '. Congratulations!';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'SCISSORS' && computerSelection == 'ROCK') {
    computerScore += 2;
    return playerSelection + ' loses vs ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
  } else return 'Enter a valid move! Refresh the damn page!';
}

function win_condition() {
  if (humanScore == 5) {
    return 'Player Wins!';
  }
  if (computerScore == 5) {
    return 'Computer wins!';
  }
}
```

Comment: I correct some things in this code. Check revisions.

Comment: This really helped. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code as highlighted in comment section:

1. Functions `win_condition` and `game` are never called.
2. Functions `win_condition` and `playGround` returns processed value but are accepted back.
3. `if( humanScore === 5 )` or `if( computerScore === 5 )` are always false. Condition to process is `humanScore <= 5 || computerScore <= 5`
4. `if(humanScore <= 5 || computerScore <= 5)` This will fail even if a player has more than 5 score.

```js
let winner = 0;
let humanScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

function initializeGame() {
  let playerSelection = prompt(' Enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors');
  let computerSelection = computerPlay();

  let msg = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  console.log(msg);
  if (humanScore <= 5 && computerScore <= 5) {
    console.log('Current score: Human: ', humanScore, ' Computer: ', computerScore)
    setTimeout(initializeGame, 0);
  } else {
    console.log(win_condition());
  }
}

function computerPlay() {
  let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 + 1));
  if (number == 1)
    return 'Rock';
  else if (number == 2)
    return 'Paper';
  else return 'Scissors';
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  playerSelection = playerSelection.toUpperCase();
  computerSelection = computerSelection.toUpperCase();
  if (playerSelection === 'ROCK' && computerSelection === 'SCISSORS') {
    humanScore += 1;
    return playerSelection + ' wins vs ' + computerSelection + '. Congratulations!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'ROCK' && computerSelection === 'PAPER') {
    computerScore += 2;
    return playerSelection + ' loses vs ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'ROCK' && computerSelection === 'ROCK') {
    return playerSelection + ' ties with ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'PAPER' && computerSelection === 'ROCK') {
    humanScore += 1;
    return playerSelection + ' wins vs ' + computerSelection + '. Congratulations!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'PAPER' && computerSelection === 'PAPER') {
    return playerSelection + ' ties with ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'PAPER' && computerSelection === 'SCISSORS') {
    computerScore += 2;
    return playerSelection + ' loses vs ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'SCISSORS' && computerSelection === 'SCISSORS') {
    return playerSelection + ' ties with ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'SCISSORS' && computerSelection === 'PAPER') {
    humanScore += 1;
    return playerSelection + ' wins vs ' + computerSelection + '. Congratulations!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'SCISSORS' && computerSelection === 'ROCK') {
    computerScore += 2;
    return playerSelection + ' loses vs ' + computerSelection + '. Try again!';
  } else return 'Enter a valid move! Refresh the damn page!';
}

function win_condition() {
  if (humanScore > 5) {
    return 'Player Wins!';
  }
  if (computerScore > 5) {
    return 'Computer wins!';
  }
}

initializeGame();
```